# How to get an element from a list with coordinates

Tags: python, list, coordinates, extract

i have recently started learning Python and i have come across this problem:
I am returning a coordinate value as a list element in a function and i need to extract this from a list format and store in separate ints.

```
nextMove=[' ']*4
nextMove[0]=[1,2]
nextMove[1]=[3,4]
nextMove[2]=[4,5]
nextMove[3]=[6,7]

# now if i want to get only 1 and store in x ..
```

If not possible then please do suggest an alternative to this situation. 
Thanking you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do multiple value assignments using tuple syntax- then you have `x` and `y` as separate values. If you don't need to use `y`, just keep it as this and have `y` as a throwaway value.

```
>>> x, y = nextMove[0]
>>> x
1
>>> y
2
```

If that is what you mean?

---

If you do only want `x`, you could create a list of the desired values:

```
>>> [x for x, y in nextMove]
[1, 3, 4, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have here, is a list of lists.

```
nextMove=[' ']*4
```

`nextMove` looks like `[' ',' ',' ',' ']`

```
nextMove[0]=[1,2]
```

`nextMove` looks like `[[1,2],' ',' ',' ']`

```
nextMove[1]=[3,4]
nextMove[2]=[4,5]
nextMove[3]=[6,7]
```

`nextMove` looks like `[[1,2],[3,4],[4,5],[6,7]]`

to get `1`, you can do

```
x = nextMove[0][0]
```

because `nextMove[0]` is the value `[1,2]`, where the `0`'th index is `1`